# Smart Detection - Failure Anomalies - Alert create manually using ARM templates for existing App Insights

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I have few app insight and Alerts (Smart Detection - Failure Anomalies) which already created in past. As you all know "Classic Alert" will be retired on 31st March 2019.

In my scenario, I want to Create New alert manually by ARM templates. Previously it was  "Failure Anomalies - appinsightname01" of "type": "Microsoft.Insights/alertRules". Here, appinsightname01 is an application insight name and this alert created automatically on app insight.

Now, after 31st August this will no longer support so I want to create new using ARM templates Manually.

It's supported using code as we create "MetricAlert, AuditLogs, LogSearch" ?

Please give me your views.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reaching out!

You may use the below ARM template for Failure Anomalies v2 (non-classic) alert rule:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "microsoft.alertsmanagement/smartdetectoralertrules",
            "apiVersion": "2019-03-01",
            "name": "Failure Anomalies - my-app",
            "properties": {
                  "description": "Detects a spike in the failure rate of requests or dependencies",
                  "state": "Enabled",
                  "severity": "2",
                  "frequency": "PT1M",
                  "detector": {
                  "id": "FailureAnomaliesDetector"
                  },
                  "scope": ["/subscriptions/00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/microsoft.insights/components/my-app"],
                  "actionGroups": {
                        "groupIds": ["/subscriptions/00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/resourcegroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/MyActionGroup"]
                  }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/proactive-arm-config#failure-anomalies-v2-non-classic-alert-rule

Hope this helps!