# Deleted Smart Detection type alerts

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-alerts

I am very new in Azure App Insights and accidently deleted an existing classic Smart Detection type alert. Is there a way to recover it?

Answer (score 0):

***AFAIK, We can not recover the Configuration of Deleted smart detection, Instead of that we have to create new alert rule with same configuration .***

For more information Please refer this ***Microsoft Documentation*** : [***Smart Detection - Failure Anomalies***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/proactive-failure-diagnostics) & [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56939663/smart-detection-failure-anomalies-alert-create-manually-using-arm-templates)