# Azure ARM template creating duplicate resources

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager

Deploying incrementally an ARM template with a simple Application Insight resource, is automatically creating **FailureAnomaliesDetector** alert rule. Which is a problem in case such rule already exists.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
            "apiVersion": "2020-02-02",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "name": "AiApp",
            "kind": "web",
            "properties": {
                "Application_Type": "web",
                "IngestionMode": "ApplicationInsights",
                "SamplingPercentage": 12.5,
                "publicNetworkAccessForIngestion": "Enabled",
                "publicNetworkAccessForQuery": "Enabled"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "microsoft.insights/actionGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
            "name": "ActionGroup",
            "location": "Global",
            "properties": {
                "groupShortName": "AiApp",
                "enabled": true,
                "emailReceivers": "[createObject('emailAddress','john@example.com','name','email','useCommonAlertSchema',true())]"
            },
            "dependsOn": [ "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', 'AiApp')]" ]
        },
        {
            "type": "microsoft.alertsmanagement/smartdetectoralertrules",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "AlertAnomalies",
            "location": "global",
            "dependsOn": [ "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/actionGroups', 'ActionGroup')]" ],
            "properties": {
                "description": "Failure Anomalies notifies you of an unusual rise in the rate of failed HTTP requests or dependency calls.",
                "state": "Enabled",
                "severity": "Sev2",
                "frequency": "PT1M",
                "detector": {
                    "id": "FailureAnomaliesDetector"
                },
                "scope": [ "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', 'AiApp')]" ],
                "actionGroups": {
                    "groupIds": [ "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/actionGroups', 'ActionGroup')]" ]
                }
            }
        }        
    ]
    }
```

I was not able to find any hint in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.insights/components?tabs=json) to stop it creating for my case unwanted rule. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

We have tried with the below ARM template to create simple Application insight resource and can able to deploy successfully without creating `FailureAnomaliesDetector` .

***TEMPLATE:-***

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
"name": {
"type": "string"
},
"type": {
"type": "string"
},
"regionId": {
"type": "string"
},
"tagsArray": {
"type": "object"
},
"requestSource": {
"type": "string"
},
"workspaceResourceId": {
"type": "string"
}
},
"resources": [
{
"name": "[parameters('name')]",
"type": "microsoft.insights/components",
"location": "[parameters('regionId')]",
"tags": "[parameters('tagsArray')]",
"apiVersion": "2020-02-02-preview",
"dependsOn": [],
"properties": {
"ApplicationId": "[parameters('name')]",
"Application_Type": "[parameters('type')]",
"Flow_Type": "Redfield",
"Request_Source": "[parameters('requestSource')]",
"WorkspaceResourceId": "[parameters('workspaceResourceId')]"
}
}
```

***OUTPUT DETAILS:-***
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

For more information please refer this [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56939663/smart-detection-failure-anomalies-alert-create-manually-using-arm-templates) .

Comment: Well that is the case, it works fine without it, but if you define it, than you have a problem. I must deploy it because the alert group with email addresses is attached to the rule.

Comment: Hello @Jan, As per my understanding , If we want to create an alert with email address then we can add into our script as well. If we don't want then we can use the above template.